# Query design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm

How to do something like :

```
$user = $query->table('user')->select('name','email')->where('id > 3');
```

I mean,
How to make the query know that the action ends in `where('id > 3')` so it will execute ?
Then, when we add `->orderBy('date')`, it won't execute after the query is finished build up..

Is it possible to do this ?

Should there be `exec()` method at the very end of action ?

However, I see Laravel can do [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries/)

Comment: @NishantSolanki Oops sorry for my bad example.. What I want to know is how to make the query know that it has reached ';' or we can say it has build up his query.. [I've edited my example haha]

Comment: it uses `get()` to execute a query...

Comment: @NishantSolanki Really? So, it's impossible to do it, right ?

Comment: why impossible?? everything is possible.. it uses get to execute a query.. so before the get function is called the query has ended building..

Comment: @NishantSolanki I mean it's impossible to know that it has reached the ';' and to execute it and fetch the data without get()

Comment: its nothing to do with `;`.. we use it for `line break in php`. if you are calling a query inside brackets `()` you dont need a `;`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like the following, It works fine

```
$user = $query->table('user')->select('name','email')->where('id' ,'>' 3)->get();
```